# How can I check if a PICKLIST value is not selected?

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, account

```
 for(Account a : accounts) {
    noOfOpp = a.Opportunities.size();

    if( isEmpty(a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c) == true ) {
        if(noOfActiveOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Active';
        } else if(noOfOpenOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Open';
        } else if(noOfInactiveOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Inactive';
        } else if(noOfLostOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Lost';
        } else {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'None';
        }
    } else {
        a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Bye';
    }
}
```

isEmpty() return an error `Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: isEmpty(String) at line 42 column 13`

ISPICKVAL doesn't work except in formula fields.

Comment: never forget to mark answer correct if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think correct syntax for calling `isEmpty()` is `String.isEmpty(pass your string here)`

[See this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isEmpty)

So you have to use this: `String.isEmpty(a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c)`

Comment: Or simply `String.isEmpty(a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c)`. :)

Comment: @Sebastian great catch :) updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for(Account a : accounts) {
    noOfOpp = a.Opportunities.size();

    if( a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c == null ) {
        if(noOfActiveOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Active';
        } else if(noOfOpenOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Open';
        } else if(noOfInactiveOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Inactive';
        } else if(noOfLostOpp > 0) {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Lost';
        } else {
            a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'None';
        }
    } else {
        a.Client_Account_Status__c = 'Bye';
    }
}
```

Comment: That code does not evaluate for empty (''), only for null.